# How to make fast the import of an excel file containing more than 5000 lines into sqlite database with django

Tags: django, python-3.x, sqlite

Import xls file (more than 5000 lines) into my sqlite database takes so long.

```
def importeradsl(request):
if "GET" == request.method:
    else:
        excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
        #you may put validations here to check extension or file size
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_file)
        #getting a particular sheet by name out of many sheets
        worksheet = wb["Sheet 1"]
        #iterating over the rows and getting value from each cell in row
        for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
            row_data = list()
            for cell in row:
                row_data.append(str(cell.value))
            #Get content fields DerangementCuivre models
            #Client
            nd = row_data[0]
            nom_client = row_data[3]
            nd_contact = row_data[4]
            #Categorie
            code_categorie = row_data[6]
            acces_reseau = row_data[8]
            etat = row_data[9]
            origine = row_data[10]
            code_sig = row_data[11]
            agent_sig = row_data[13]
            date_sig = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[14]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            date_essai = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[15]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            agent_essai = row_data[18]
            try:
                date_ori = dt.datetime.strptime(row_data[19], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            except ValueError as e:
                print ("Vous", e)
            else:
                date_ori = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[19]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            agent_ori = row_data[20]
            code_ui = row_data[21]
            equipe = row_data[22]
            sous_traitant = row_data[23]
            date_pla = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[24]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            date_rel = dt.datetime.strftime(parse(row_data[25]), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            date_releve = dt.datetime.strptime(row_data[25], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            date_essais = dt.datetime.strptime(row_data[15], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
            pst = pytz.timezone('Africa/Dakar')
            date_releve = pst.localize(date_releve)
            utc = pytz.UTC
            date_releve = date_releve.astimezone(utc)
            date_essais = pst.localize(date_essais)
            date_essais = date_essais.astimezone(utc)
            code_rel = row_data[26]
            localisation = row_data[27]
            cause = row_data[28]
            commentaire = row_data[29]
            agent_releve = row_data[30]
            centre_racc = row_data[32]
            rep = row_data[33]
            srp = row_data[34]
            delai = (date_releve - date_essais).total_seconds()
            dali = divmod(delai, 86400)[0]
            semaine = date_releve.isocalendar()[1]
            mois = date_releve.month
            annee = date_releve.year
            if dali > 7:
                etats = "PEX PLUS"
            else:
                etats = "PEX"
            #Enregistrer un client
            Client(nd=nd, nom=nom_client, mobile=nd_contact).save()
            #Enregistrer la categorie
            #Code pour nom categorie - renseigner plus tard
            Categorie(code_categorie=code_categorie, nom="Public").save()
            #Enregistrer agent de signalisation
            AgentSig(matricule=agent_sig, nom="Awa").save()
            #Enregistrer agent d'essai
            AgentEssai(matricule=agent_essai).save()
            #Enregister agent d'orientation
            AgentOri(matricule=agent_ori).save()
            #Enregistrer agent de relève
            AgentRel(matricule=agent_releve).save()
            #Enregistrer le sous-traitant
            SousTraitant(nom=sous_traitant).save()
            #Enregistrer le centre
            Centre(code=centre_racc).save()
            #Enregistrer ui
            UniteIntervention(code_ui=code_ui, 
            sous_traitant=SousTraitant.objects.get(nom=sous_traitant)).save()
            #Enregistrer le repartiteur
            Repartiteur(code=rep, crac=Centre.objects.get(code=centre_racc)).save()
            #Enregistrer team
            Equipe(nom=equipe, unite=UniteIntervention.objects.get(code_ui=code_ui)).save()
            #Enregistrer le SR
            SousRepartiteur(code=srp, rep=Repartiteur.objects.get(code=rep)).save()
            #Enregistrer le drangement
            DerangementAdsl(acces_reseau=acces_reseau,
                            nd_client=Client.objects.get(nd=nd),
                            categorie=Categorie(code_categorie=code_categorie),
                            etat=etat,
                            origine=origine,
                            code_sig=code_sig,
                            agent_sig=AgentSig.objects.get(matricule=agent_sig),
                            date_sig=date_sig,
                            date_essai=date_essai,
                            agent_essai=AgentEssai.objects.get(matricule=agent_essai),
                            date_ori=date_ori,
                            agent_ori=AgentOri.objects.get(matricule=agent_ori),
                            sous_traitant=SousTraitant.objects.get(nom=sous_traitant),
                            unite_int = UniteIntervention.objects.get(code_ui=code_ui),
                            date_pla=date_pla,
                            date_rel=date_rel,
                            code_rel=code_rel,
                            code_local=localisation,
                            cause=cause,
                            comment_cause=commentaire,
                            agent_rel=AgentRel.objects.get(matricule=agent_releve),
                            centre=Centre.objects.get(code=centre_racc),
                            rep=Repartiteur.objects.get(code=rep),
                            srep=SousRepartiteur.objects.get(code=srp),
                            delai=dali,
                            etat_vr=etats,
                            semaine=semaine,
                            mois=mois,
                            annee=annee).save()
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few things that are incorrect.
I propose to you the following approach:

1. Make your code more readable
2. Remove useless queries
3. Avoid related records duplication
4. Cache out your related instances.
5. Use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Looking at your code, with a rough estimation, per csv record, you will get over 30 SQL queries per row, that's a bit much...

## 1. Make you code more readable.

Your parsing logic can be DRYed, a lot.

First, identify what you do with your data.
From my point of view, 2 main functions:

Do nothing:

```py
def no_transformation(value)
    return str(value)
```

Parse dates

```py
def strptime(value):
    """
    I can't really tell what your 'parse' function does, I let it be but it might 
    be interesting adding your logic in here
    """
    return dt.datetime.strptime(parse(str(value)), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Now, you can declare your parser configuration:

```py
PARSER_CONFIG=(
    #(column_index, variable_name, transformation_function)
    (0,'nd',no_transformation),
    (10,'origine',no_transformation),
    (11,'code_sig',no_transformation),
    (13,'agent_sig',no_transformation),
    (14,'date_sig',strptime),
    (15,'date_essai',strptime),
    (18,'agent_essai',no_transformation),
    (19,'date_ori',strptime),
    (20,'agent_ori',no_transformation),
    (21,'code_ui',no_transformation),
    (22,'equipe',no_transformation),
    (23,'sous_traitant',no_transformation),
    (24,'date_pla',strptime),
    (25,'date_rel',strptime),
    (26,'code_rel',no_transformation),
    (27,'localisation',no_transformation),
    (28,'cause',no_transformation),
    (29,'commentaire',no_transformation),
    (3,'nom_client',no_transformation),
    (30,'agent_releve',no_transformation),
    (32,'centre_racc',no_transformation),
    (33,'rep',no_transformation),
    (34,'srp',no_transformation),
    (4,'nd_contact',no_transformation),
    (6,'code_categorie',no_transformation),
    (8,'acces_reseau',no_transformation),
    (9,'etat',no_transformation),
    (15',date_essais',strptime),
    (19',date_ori',strptime),
    (25',date_releve',strptime),
)
```

Now, you know how to parse your data, and how to name it.
Let just put that stuff into a dict.

```py
def parse(row):
    """Transform a row into a dict
    
    Args:
        row (tuple): Your row's data
    
    Returns:
        dict: Your parsed data, named into a dict.
    """
    return {
        key:tranfsorm(row[index]) for index, key, transform in PARSER_CONFIG
    }
```

From here, your parser is *way* more readable, you know exactly what you're doing with your data.

Wrapping this up all together, you should get:

```py
PARSER_CONFIG=(
    #(column_index, variable_name, transformation_function)
    #...
)
def no_transformation(value)
    return str(value)

def strptime(value)
    return str(value)

def parse(row):
    """Transform a row into a dict
    
    Args:
        row (tuple): Your row's data
    
    Returns:
        dict: Your parsed data, named into a dict.
    """
    return {
        key:tranfsorm(row[index]) for index, key, transform in PARSER_CONFIG
    }

for row in rows:
    item = parse(row) #< Your data, without related instances yet....
```

Still have some work to create your related instances, but we'll get there eventually.

## 2. Removing useless queries.

You do :

```py
#...First, your create a record
Client(nd=nd, nom=nom_client, mobile=nd_contact).save()
#... Then you fetch it when saving DerangementAdsl
nd_client=Client.objects.get(nd=nd)
```

While a more pythonic way of doing this would be:

```py
#... You create and assign your istance.
client = Client(nd=item.get('nd'), 
                nom=item.get('nom_client'), 
                mobile=item.get('nd_contact')).save()
#...
nd_client=client
```

You just earned one SQL query/row! Doing the same logic for each models, and you'll earn around 20 queries per row!

```py
categorie=Categorie.objects.create(code_categorie=item.get('code_categorie'), nom="Public"),
#Enregistrer agent de signalisation
agent_sig=AgentSig.objects.create(matricule=item.get('agent_sig'), nom="Awa"),
#Enregistrer agent d'essai
agent_essai=AgentEssai.objects.create(matricule=item.get('agent_essai')),
#Enregister agent d'orientation
agent_ori=AgentOri.objects.create(matricule=item.get('agent_ori')),
#Enregistrer agent de relève
agent_rel=AgentRel.objects.create(matricule=item.get('agent_releve')),
#Enregistrer le sous-traitant
sous_traitant=SousTraitant.objects.create(nom=item.get('sous_traitant')),
#Enregistrer le centre
centre=Centre.objects.create(code=item.get('centre_racc')),
#Enregistrer ui
unite_int=UniteIntervention.objects.create(code_ui=item.get('code_ui'), sous_traitant=sous_traitant), # < You earn one extrat query with sous_traitant
#Enregistrer le repartiteur
rep=Repartiteur.objects.create(code=item.get('rep'), crac=centre), # < You earn one extrat query with centre
#Enregistrer team
equipe=Equipe.objects.create(nom=item.get('equipe')), unite=unite_int),# < You earn one extrat query with unite_int
#Enregistrer le SR
srep=SousRepartiteur.objects.create(code=item.get('srp'), rep=rep),# < You earn one extrat query with rep
```

## 3. Avoid related records duplication

Now there is one big issue:

Considering you have multiple rows for each `client`,
you'll eventually find yourself with many duplicates, and you do not want that.
Instead of using `create`, you should go with [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create).

Please note it returns a tuple: (instance, created)
So.... your code should go like:

```py
categorie, categorie_created=Categorie.objects.get_or_create(code_categorie=item.get('code_categorie'), nom="Public"),
agent_sig, agent_sig_created=AgentSig.objects.get_or_create(matricule=item.get('agent_sig'), nom="Awa"),
agent_essai, agent_essai_created=AgentEssai.objects.get_or_create(matricule=item.get('agent_essai')),
agent_ori, agent_ori_created=AgentOri.objects.get_or_create(matricule=item.get('agent_ori')),
agent_rel, agent_rel_created=AgentRel.objects.get_or_create(matricule=item.get('agent_releve')),
sous_traitant, sous_traitant_created=SousTraitant.objects.get_or_create(nom=item.get('sous_traitant')),
centre, centre_created=Centre.objects.get_or_create(code=item.get('centre_racc')),
unite_int, unite_int_created=UniteIntervention.objects.get_or_create(code_ui=item.get('code_ui'), sous_traitant=sous_traitant)
rep, rep_created=Repartiteur.objects.get_or_create(code=item.get('rep'), crac=centre)
equipe, equipe_created=Equipe.objects.get_or_create(nom=item.get('equipe')), unite=unite_int
srep, srep_created=SousRepartiteur.objects.get_or_create(code=item.get('srp'), rep=rep)
```

Tadaaaaam, you'll create records that are "only" necessary for your related objects.

## 4. Caching out your related objects.

As in previous topic, I consider you have multiple rows for each related instance,
and for each row, you will still get to fetch that from your DB.

It's OK I guess if you're using SQLite in memory, it won't be as slow as with other DBs, still, it'll be a bottleneck.
You could use an approach like:

```py
MODEL_CACHE = {}
def get_related_instance(model, **kwargs):
    key = (model,kwargs)
    if key in MODEL_CACHE:
        return instance MODEL_CACHE[key]
    else:
        instance, create = model.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
        MODEL_CACH[key]=instance
    return instance

# Instead of having previous lines now you end up with:
categorie = get_related_instance(Categorie,code_categorie=item.get('code_categorie'), nom="Public"),
agent_sig = get_related_instance(AgentSig,matricule=item.get('agent_sig'), nom="Awa"),
agent_essai = get_related_instance(AgentEssai,matricule=item.get('agent_essai')),
agent_ori = get_related_instance(AgentOri,matricule=item.get('agent_ori')),
agent_rel = get_related_instance(AgentRel,matricule=item.get('agent_releve')),
sous_traitant = get_related_instance(SousTraitant,nom=item.get('sous_traitant')),
centre = get_related_instance(Centre,code=item.get('centre_racc')),
unite_int = get_related_instance(UniteIntervention,code_ui=item.get('code_ui'), sous_traitant=sous_traitant)
rep = get_related_instance(Repartiteur,code=item.get('rep'), crac=centre)
equipe = get_related_instance(Equipe,nom=item.get('equipe')), unite=unite_int
srep = get_related_instance(SousRepartiteur,code=item.get('srp'), rep=rep)
```

I cannot tell how much you'll gain thanks to that, it really depends on the data set you're trying to import,
but from experience, it's quite drastic!

## 5 Use [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

You are doing

```py
for row in rows:
    DerangementAdsl(...your data...).save() #<That's one DB call
```

That's one SQL query per row, while you could do:

```py
ITEMS = []
for row in rows:
    #...Your parsing we saw previously...
    ITEMS.append(DerangementAdsl(**item))
DerangementAdsl.objects.bulk_create(ITEMS) #<That's one DB call
```

## Putting it all together!

```py
PARSER_CONFIG=(
    #(column_index, variable_name, transformation_function)
    #...
)
def no_transformation(value)
    return str(value)

def strptime(value)
    return str(value)

MODEL_CACHE = {}

def get_related_instance(model, **kwargs):
    key = (mode,kwargs)
    if key in MODEL_CACHE:
        return instance MODEL_CACHE[key]
    else:
        instance, create = model.objects.get_or_create(**kwargs)
        MODEL_CACH[key]=instance
    return instance

def parse(row):
    """Transform a row into a dict
    
    Args:
        row (tuple): Your row's data
    
    Returns:
        dict: Your parsed data, named into a dict.
    """
    item= {
        key:tranfsorm(row[index]) for index, key, transform in PARSER_CONFIG
    }
    item.update({
        'categorie': get_related_instance(Categorie,code_categorie=item.get('code_categorie'), nom="Public"),
        'agent_sig': get_related_instance(AgentSig,matricule=item.get('agent_sig'), nom="Awa"),
        'agent_essai': get_related_instance(AgentEssai,matricule=item.get('agent_essai')),
        'agent_ori': get_related_instance(AgentOri,matricule=item.get('agent_ori')),
        'agent_rel': get_related_instance(AgentRel,matricule=item.get('agent_releve')),
        'sous_traitant': get_related_instance(SousTraitant,nom=item.get('sous_traitant')),
        'centre': get_related_instance(Centre,code=item.get('centre_racc')),
        'unite_int': get_related_instance(UniteIntervention,code_ui=item.get('code_ui'), sous_traitant=sous_traitant)
        'rep': get_related_instance(Repartiteur,code=item.get('rep'), crac=centre)
        'equipe': get_related_instance(Equipe,nom=item.get('equipe')), unite=unite_int
        'srep': get_related_instance(SousRepartiteur,code=item.get('srp'), rep=rep)
    })
    return item

def importeradsl(request):
    #I skip your conditions for readility
    ITEMS = []
    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
        ITEMS.append(DerangementAdsl(**parse(row)))
    
    DerangementAdsl.objects.bulk_create(ITEMS)
```

### Conclusion

Following those recommendation, you should end up with an optimized script that will run **way** faster than the original one, and be **way** more [readable and pythonic](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Roughly, depending on your dataset, 5k lines should run somewhere between 10 seconds up to few minutes.

If each row's related instance (`client`,`category`...) is unique, I'd use a more sophisticated approach looping multiple times over your dataset to create related models using [bulk_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) and cache them out like:

```py
CLIENTS = []
for row in rows:
    CLIENTS.append(Client(**client_parser(row)))
clients=Client.objects.bulk_create(CLIENTS) # You Create *all* your client with only one DB call!
```

Then, you cache all created clients. You do the same for all your related models and eventually you'll load your data making a dozen of DB calls, but it really depends on your business logic here: It should be engineered to handle duplicated records too.

Comment: Thank you Julien ! You're awesome.

Comment: Looks like your row is a string?

Comment: It might be some issue in date parsing: I did not handle your `try` part in my example