# how to import csv data to postgres database using python

Tags: python, django, excel, postgresql, pycharm

I am trying to import the data in my excel sheet to the postgresql database using python, and when i do that i get the following error.

i have already converted my excel to csv and then tried using the 'copy' statement to import the data to postgres database.

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("host=localhost dbname=djangotest user=postgres password=*******")
cur = conn.cursor()

with open('C:\\Users\\********\\Desktop\\excelsheet.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f) # Skip the header row.
    cur.copy_from(f, 'us_arrays', sep=',')

conn.commit()
```

````
psycopg2.errors.BadCopyFileFormat: missing data for column "ip_address_or_service_machine"
CONTEXT:  COPY us_arrays, line 1: "(CMDB)",.Device Type,.Frame or Data Tier,.Corp Device,.Encrypt Enabled,.Dedicated Device,".IP Addres..."```
````

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you also provide a sample of this CSV file? That might help other people to reproduce your error.

Comment: Header,Header,Header,(this goes on for about 22 columns), value,value,value,value,,,,,,,,,,,value,value,value

Comment: I am thinking that, the extra spaces are also considered and a delimeter is placed. and when importing to the database, even the extra comma's are being considered and finally some columns are missing values. I am not quite sure if that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the error text (`missing data for column`), it seems like the number of columns in `us_arrays` table doesn't match the number of columns in your CSV file. You can also use `columns` keyword attribute when calling `copy_from` to specify the database table columns which should be populated from your file. Read more about it [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_from).

A common scenario would be having a database table with 3 columns, e.g. `id`, `num`, `data` and a CSV file with only 2 columns `num` and `data`. Without specifying `columns`, the `copy_from` function would import `num` from the CSV file into `id` database column, `data` into `num`, and there would be no data left to import into `data` database column.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is tagged as Django, so I'll consider you want to import something linked to `Model`.

I give a detail explanation on how to speed up XL loading in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58418482/how-to-make-fast-the-import-of-an-excel-file-containing-more-than-5000-lines-int/58418737?noredirect=1#comment103288275_58418737)
Now, if performance is not an issue (your dataset is not too big, and do not have FKs), you can simply use [Django Import Export](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Adding mixins to your Admin, you won't have to bother about file conversion and will give you `diff` when loading your file